# Wordpress : pre_get_posts and passing arguments from author.php to function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get pre_get_posts to work with passing arguments. I have the following function in my function.php file of my theme.

```
function cpt_on_author_page( $query, $user_id ) {   
    if ( $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'programs' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
        $query->set( 'meta_key' , 'show_program_editors');
        $query->set( 'meta_value' , $user_id);              
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cpt_on_author_page' );
```

I call this function via my author.php file via this code:

```
 do_action( 'pre_get_posts',$user_id );
```

On the output page, I am getting

```
 Missing argument 2 for cpt_on_author_page()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing line 1 to `function cpt_on_author_page( $query ) {`

If you need to use `$user_id` (the ID of the current author) inside your function, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
$user_id = $author->ID;
```

You shouldn't need `do_action( 'pre_get_posts',$user_id );` at all.

**Update (after discussion in this answer's comments):**

To show all posts having a meta value of `kam` in `kam`'s author archive, you could do something like this:

```
function cpt_on_author_page( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_author() ) {

        $users = get_users();
        $ids = array();
        foreach ( $users as $user ) {
            $ids[] = $user->ID;
        }
        $query->set( 'author__in' , $ids ); 

        $author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
        $query->set( 'meta_value' , $author->user_login );

    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cpt_on_author_page' );
```

Notes: This assumes each author's nicename is the same as their username.

Comment: thankx, i do that `function cpt_on_author_page( $query ) {
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
$user_id = $author->ID;
    if ( $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'programs' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
  $query->set( 'meta_key' , 'show_program_editors');
  $query->set( 'meta_value' , $user_id); 

  
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cpt_on_author_page' );` but when go to author name (kam) its not show me any post for him

Comment: Has author `kam` published any posts of type `programs` where a `show_program_editors` meta key has been given a value of `$user_id`?

Comment: tha author kam not published any post, iam 'admin' add post and save it by custom meta key as 'kam' like this   `function save_programs_meta( $post_id = false, $post = false ) {

    // Check post type for teachers
 
  if ( $post->post_type == 'programs') {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, 'show_program_editors',$_POST['show_program_editors'] );
   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'small_pic',$_POST['small_pic'] );
   }

  }`

Comment: "tha author kam not published any post" <--- this is probably why you're not seeing any posts for him on his author archive page.

Comment: So on the post archive page, you want to show only posts that have a meta value of `kam`? Is that right?

Comment: Or is `kam` an author? Sorry for not quite following.

Comment: in `kam` archive i want to show only posts that have a meta value of `kam` only

Comment: So `kam` is a) an author's username and b) a meta value

Comment: yes ,, but the post add by admin not by kam , and i wont to show it in kam archive

Comment: If admin wrote the post then by default it will not show in kam's post archive.

Comment: mmm, can i do that `$query->set( 'authoor_id' , $user_id);`

Comment: i need to show in kam archive all post that have meta key 'kam' and post author any user

Comment: mmmm, ok but if i open the author 'sami' how can i see all post that meta key is 'sami' ??